# VBA scrape price from website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to make excel scrape a price of flight from website
https://skrendu.lt/lt/flights/VNOc-OPOc/2016-09-15/1

```
Sub Macro()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://skrendu.lt/lt/flights/VNOc-OPOc/2016-09-15/1"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:010"))

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.document

Dim sTR As String
sTR = Doc.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding ng-scope")(0).innerText
Range(A1) = sTR

IE.Quit
End Sub
```

However I get Error 400. Any ideas on why is it not working?

The part I use from the HTML is:

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSmk4.jpg)

Comment: IE.Quit ?    ???   ?

Comment: for start I would not quit ie until the end of the sub. Move that line to the end

Comment: I have tried it already, still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me. I noticed you are missing the `"` around the range A1.

Here's some working code, you may need to adjust the wait or devise a better wait for page to load technique.

```
Sub FindPrice()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://skrendu.lt/lt/flights/VNOc-OPOc/2016-09-15/1"
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:06")) ' Wait a bit

        While .readystate <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .busy
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        Wend

        Range("A1").Value = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding ng-scope")(0).innerText
    End With

End Sub
```